# how to create binary of iphone application

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

On reading the iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf, i came across the term *binary*. This is the paragraph found in the pdf:

*To submit your application through iTunes Connect and get it posted on the

App Store successfully, make sure you have the following: 
Application binary (includes 57px icon), large 512px icon for use on the  App Store, 
primary screenshot, contract information, export compliance information and applica- 
tion metadata*

It is also mentioned that the binary should be a zipped file.

Can anyone please explain what is a binary and how to create one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, what Apple really means is the complete Application Bundle. You create it by building your project with XCode for the iPhone OS target. Don't forget to sign it for App Store Distribution during the XCode build process, as described in Apple's iTunes Connect / Developer Pogram Portal documentation.

Answer (score 35):

This is the method I found out. Please correct me if there is any mistake:

Find the file ending in ".app" in the Products folder of your application in Xcode.
Right-click on it and choose Show In Finder.
From there, right-click again and choose Compress.

The resulting zipped file is the binary of your iphone application.

Comment: The zipping is a requirement to be able to upload it (since an app is a magic folder), not strictly a part of the definition. But, yes, the .app folder that is your build product is what iTunes Connect means by "application binary".

Answer (score 0):

To submit an app update, just log on to iTunes Connect (itunesconnect.apple.com) and click on "Manage Applications".  Click on the application you want to update.  From there, there is the icon of the app and next to it, a button that says "Add Version".  Click it, and from there just follow iTunes Connect's advice!  If you submit a NEW application with the same name but a different version, it will just add a NEW application to the app store (if it doesn't give you an error)!  Then, v1.0 and v1.1 will BOTH be available for download.