# iPhone Binary for the App Store

Tags: iphone, binary

After reading another thread about creating the binary for App Store submission ([how to create binary of iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497547/how-to-create-binary-of-iphone-application)) I'm still a bit confused.

Do I just compress the app in the build/Release-iphoneos directory?

Has anyone submitted a binary recently that can let me know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you should now have a build directectory called 'distribution-iphoneos' and then you compress the app in that.

Have you followed the instructions on Apple's website, In the iTunes Connect docs?

That's how I learned.

Comment: Which docs?  I've read through the iTunes Connect Developer Guide and it doesn't say anything about how to make the binary...

Comment: page 51 of the pdf  - iPhone Program User Guide.

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded binary 1 day before.goto **BUILD/DISTRIBUTION-IPHONEOS/** you will have your **.app** file compress that and using **APPLICATION LOADER** u need to upload that compressed file to app store.

Hope this helps you.